# Honda civic 2018 - 11,500km but no oil change?

Tags: oil, civic

Just bought a used car (that is currently in preparation and will be ready in three days).

Spec:

- Honda civic 2018
- 2 years of usage
- 11,500km

Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about cars and mechanic and just realized that the carfax report does not seems to listed a oil change.

My questions:

1. Looking at the carfax report, does my assumption is good?
2. If the assumption is good, would it represents an issue to run this car with the same oil during two years? (even if only 11,500km)

Thank you

[image]

UPDATE:

Thank you all for the valuable informations provided in this thread, I really appreciate your inputs!

For information, I have asked the dealer to take a picture of the oil life computer metric and it was surprisingly at 80%. So two options here: the last owner did the oil replacement job himself (or by a small garage that did not report the service maintenance). Or the last owner just reset the metric without doing the actual oil change (which would have been very stupid).

[image]

Comment: If the "oil usage" indicator in the car says it doesn't need changing, it doesn't need changing. The idea that you have to change the oil every 5000 km / 3000 miles is ancient history. FWIW my current car has an oil change interval of 30,000 km, and it's still running fine after only 5 oil changes in 11 years.

Comment: I don't know those reports, but the car was serviced at 2300km in November 2018. Is it possible that a service also includes oil change? Though, that's almost 2years and 9000km ago and does not alter your question.

Comment: I have bought several used cars up to a year old where the dealer says the car has been serviced. This does not mean that they do unnecessary jobs that are not yet scheduled. It means they check the car over, and do anything that needs to be done.

Comment: Keep in mind that a Carfax report may well be incomplete. Carfax won't pick up any work done in an aftermarket shop that doesn't report it outside the shop, and it won't pick up work done by the owner is their garage.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I come across an incomplete or questionable service record I assume it wasn't serviced. I always recommend an oil and filter change on any used vehicle. This way you can start your own service interval and monitor things like oil consumption. I would also include things like timing belts that can cause severe engine damage when they fail. Many people will opt to sell or trade an older vehicle when a major service is due rather than pay for the service.

Answer (score 0):

Manufactures of vehicles have guidelines for oil changes. These will be found in the owners manual. They almost with no fail give an oil change requirement of miles driven and also a specified amount of time because oil degrades over time. Many times driving conditions are factored into the mileage requirements as well. Any manual I've seen requires that the oil is to be changed in 12 months even if the milage requirements have not been met. Most late model cars will earn you to get an oil service when milage requires it or it has been 12 months since the last service. If the car does not have an active service reminder lit up, I would assume that it has been serviced without the Carfax s knowledge.

Comment: Or, as happens sometimes ( <- humour ) it wasn't serviced at all.

Answer (score 0):

For info, just read this in the owner manual:

> If a Maintenance Minder indicator does not appear more than 12 months after the display is reset, change the engine oil every year

http://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/AH/ATBA1818OM/enu/ATBA1818OM.PDF

Comment: Yeah, but is that for mineral oil? The "recommended oil" on page 528 has a footnote: *"**Synthetic oil** You may also use synthetic motor oil if it is labeled with the API Certification Seal and is the specified viscosity grade."* In UK at least, we generally use synthetic oil, which does not degrade as fast as mineral oil does.

Answer (score 0):

While this is unusual, it's important to note that the Civic takes only synthetic oil (0 weight motor oil). It's right on your oil cap (0w-20) if you look under the hood. It's been that way [since 2011](https://www.wildehonda.com/honda-engine-oil-synthetic-vs-regular/).

> Starting with the 2011 models, most new Honda vehicles will come from the factory with the Honda engineered 0w-20 synthetic oil.

Synthetic oil lasts a lot longer than regular oil. 11,500 km is about 7000 miles. I tend to get 8000-9000 miles between changes (2013 Civic), and I change it when the dash starts complaining about low oil life (about 10% estimated life remaining). I used to know a guy at the Honda dealership I bought it from and he confirmed he got about the same on his vehicles. Check your dash menu for the maintenance data and it should list an estimated oil life remaining. 7000 miles in 2 years is not a lot of miles, all things considered.

I would go ahead and replace the oil anyways, since you're going to be close to needing to regardless of how much life it has left. Synthetic changes are more expensive, but your engine is designed for it, and it's offset by the longer life.